# Mockito tests are failing on verify when using @InjectMocks annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, verify

I am writing unit tests for a SpringBoot app using Mockito.
I was trying to use the `@InjectMocks` since it is the easiest and cleanest way.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTests {

@InjectMocks      
private MyService service;

@Mock
private Producer<String, RequestMessage> producer1;

@Mock
private Producer<String, RequestResult> producer2;
...
```

I have 2 main flows - in 1 I am creating and sending a request using `producer1`, and in the other due to some failure in the request creation I am sending a failure message using `producer2`.

In my unit tests I want to verify the right producer was called:

```
@Test
void start_ValidData_ShouldCreateMessageAndSendIt() throws Exception {
  ...

  verify(producer1).send(customerEmail, message);
}

@Test
void start_DataIsNotPassingValidation_ShouldSendFailureResponse() throws Exception {
  ...

  verify(producer1, never()).send(any(), any());
  verify(producer2).send(
                    argThat(message -> message.getResultStatus() == FAILED_IN_PARSE));        
}
```

When I am running the tests separately they are passing, but when running the full tests class the tests are failing on the verify line (each time a different one is failing). From the logs I was adding and from debugging, I can see that the code flow is going as expected. What made got me assume that the shared mocked producers instances are being initialized and called simultaneously from the 2 different async tests, which causes the tests to fail on the `verify`.

I was able to solve the issue using an explicit constructor for my service:

```
@BeforeEach
public void initMocks() {
    producer1 = Mockito.mock(Producer.class);
    producer2 = Mockito.mock(Producer.class);
    ...

    service = new MyService(producer1,
            producer2, ...);
}
```

But I was wondering why my tests are failing when using the `@InjectMocks` annotation?

**Edit:**
It is important to say that I've checked and sure the instances of the producers are being initialized in every run.
Also, even if it wasn't so the first test should have been passed.

Comment: Are you using JUnit version 4 or 5?

Comment: I am using 4.13.2

Comment: any update on this ? I also have the same issue